# template event fail to return context data

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This Meteor template click event is expected to print the prop `shortName` to the browser console but it prints `undefined`. Why and how to fix it? thx

```js
"use strict";

Template.subMenu.helpers({
  subMenuItems: () => {
    let task = Session.get('taskSelected');
      return SubMenuCol.find({action: task});
  }
});

Template.subMenu.events({
  'click .subMenuItem': (event) => {
    //let shortName = $(event.target).data('shortName');
    let shortName = event.currentTarget.dataset.shortName;

    console.log(shortName);
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="subMenu">
  <ul id="sub-menu">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      {{#each subMenuItems}}
        <li class="subMenuItem" data-shorName={{shortName}} data-action={{action}}>{{menuItem}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

**edit**
`shortName` was a typo, has been fixed for no avail. still giving `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I would use the data context and not use `data-*` attributes. The data context a certain element was rendered with is preserved by Blaze and is available to the event handler as its `this` context, so simply using `this.shortName` in the event handler would have given you the desired value.

```
<template name="subMenu">
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      {{#each subMenuItems}}
        <li class="sub-menu-item">{{menuItem}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

You will have it as the data context, just don't use an arrow function, which statically binds its `this` context to the one used during its definition.

```
Template.subMenu.events({
  'click .sub-menu-item'(event) {
    let shortName = this.shortName;
    console.log(shortName);
  }
});
```

---

If you opt for the custom data attributes, you should know their specification and mapping to JS. It is not 1:1 and not everything is allowed.

> - The name of a custom data attribute in HTML begins with data-. It must contain only letters, numbers and the following characters: dash (-), dot (.), colon (:), underscore (_) -- **but NOT any ASCII capital letters** (A to Z).
> - The name of a custom data attribute in Javascript is the name of the same HTML attribute but in camelCase and with no dashes, dots, etc.
>
> source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

This means that the identifier you used is illegal, and the one corresponding to `shortName` should have been `data-short-name`:

```
<li class="subMenuItem" data-short-name={{shortName}} data-action={{action}}>{{menuItem}}</li>
```

Comment: Using the data context and not data-*, could you please give answer in code? i.e. what will the html look like for `this.shortName` in the event to work?

Comment: You don't need to do anything with the HTML. It already works, as the data context inside the `#each` is the current item, and you target the item with the event handler's selector. See my note regarding the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just suffering from a typo mistake.  You left out the **t** in **data-shortName**

```
<li class="subMenuItem" data-shorName={{shortName}}>
```

Then uncomment this line and you should be good to go.

```
//let shortName = $(event.target).data('shortName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was copy & paste but your li tag has dataset 'shorName' (missing 't') rather than 'shortName'.